# delphi XE : Access violation inside LoadLibrary() call

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I get an access violation when call a DLL in an project. Both project and dll are use Chart unit (TChart). Remove Tchart from project the LoadLibrary can successful return. It also works if Tchart removed from dll. I don't understand why the chart unit can't be used in both project and dll? And how to resolve this problem.

Comment: To use it in a DLL, you should go the Delphi path and create a BPL. Which is underneath a DLL, but contains some glue code for Delphis "compiler magic".

Comment: There's no reason why TeeChart can't be used in a DLL.

Comment: @David Heffernan I'm so confused why my project can't load a dll with TeeChart. And i made a simple project and also a simple dll without do anything but all include a TeeChart. It still get crash. Any suggestion?

Comment: @STATUS_ACCESS_DENIED I'm not understand very clearly about your recommendations. Can you tell me something more about this?

Comment: @Sarah Cla: see the answer from RRUZ. Seems to be a known issue.

Comment: Sounds like RRUZ is on the money. Nothing inherently wrong with TChart in a DLL (as @STATUS implied). But looks like a TChart bug. This is why it pays to use the full version that comes with source and so you are then (more) in control of your own destiny.

Comment: Delphi forms/components in a plain DLL are known to cause trouble, while BPLs continue to be the way to go for those cases. The question doesn't really provide enough detail otherwise ;)

Comment: @STATUS Delphi forms/components only cause trouble if you do it wrong.

Comment: @STATUS If you have VCL components in a DLL, then they must stay there. The problems arise when you allow VCL components to cross the boundary. I'm sure you know all this though!! ;-)

Answer (score 7):

Sarah, this is a bug of the TChart component, located in the *TeCanvas* unit. the people of *[Steema](http://www.steema.com/)* are aware of this. you can check the next Thread  [`Delphi XE, TChart in exe and in dll`](https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=47288) in the embarcadero forums.

Comment: thinks for your answer. Depressed to know this problem is not resolved yet. Even the deadline of new pack is not definit

Answer (score 0):

I spotted this bug today while using Delphi XE and FastReport 6 VCL, when in exe I have FrxChart and in a library.
After long time consumption debugging process, I realized that only TeEngine included in both application can cause crash LoadLibrary() function.
Because link to forum is not working anymore, can I do something to repair this bug  (excluding remove charts in library)?